# Java script redirect from a popup

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup

When any user clicks on a link, I wrote the code to go to like.php. I would like to pop up a javascript window in like.php to display a message and after 5 minute I would like to redirect to another page if the user will not click ok the OK button. If the user clicks on the OK button I need to redirect sooner. I am using the followig code. Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(alert("Like Me")){
            window.location = "http://www.vsofteducation.com/development/fbupload.php";
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: And... what have **you** tried?

Answer (score 0):

Pop-ups are bad, but anyway. From your popup, you have access to the [opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) page.

```
window.opener.location = '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the popup HTML:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    window.top.location = 'http://google.fi';
}, 5000);
</script>
```

This makes the popup wait 5 seconds and then tell the parent window to go to Google.

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You Can't do it with Javascript Alert....

You can use JQuery Dialog box to do that

**Update**

function renderPopup()
{

```
var url = 'www.google.com';

var $dialog = $('<div title="popup"></div>')
    .html('Press OK')
    .dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons:
        {
           "Ok":
            function()
            {
                  window.top.location = 'www.google.com';
            }
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});

   setTimeout(function() {
    window.top.location = 'www.google.com';
   }, 5000);


}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty basic Javascript.

```
alert("Like me");
setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = "...";
}, 300000);
```

Note: if you don't know functions like `setTimeout`, maybe you should learn a bit more about Javascript and read some tutorials before asking questions here. We're not teachers, we just offer our knowledge to solve developers' problems.

**Edit**: `alert` doesn't return a value, so the `if` condition would be always false. Fixed.

Comment: But what happen , if the user will not click on the okay button. I would like to reditect after 5 minute if the user will not click on okay button and if the user will click in it need to redirect fast. Thanks

Comment: The user HAS to click on the OK button, or the X button. But you can't detect which one.

Comment: is there any way to take an action if the user is not click in the button. Means I would like to redirect if the user is not click on the button..

Comment: The page is frozen until the user clicks on the button of the `alert` popup. The user can't even close the page.
--- I also would like to know why somebody downvoted my answer.